# ESPN Sports API request specific leagues

Tags: espn

Is there any way using the `Sports API` to return a selection of **multiple, but not all, leagues?**

For example, the Request URI is `http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/?apikey=x` which allows a call for all leagues
-OR-
the Request URI is `http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/?apikey=xx` to call a specific league.

**My question is if there is any way to call `basketball` AND `baseball`?**

As opposed to calling ALL or only ONE.

Thanks!

*Note - ESPN Developer website asks questions to be posted here per website support page: 
"Got A Programming Question?
Search Stack Overflow, in some cases your question has already been answered.
For new questions, post them to Stack Overflow using the tag "ESPN"."*

Comment: Can you help out on this @rogerraymond?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no way to do this using the ESPN API.  So just wanted to let anyone else know that, along with the fact that the ESPN API is closed as of December 7 2014.

Any other questions just let me know!